# syslog-ng stopped and don't want to start

Tags: debian, log-files, syslog

I noticed lately that my syslog is empty.

I tried restarting it but i get this error:

```
$ /etc/init.d/syslog-ng reload
Reload system logging: syslog-ngsyntax error in /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf at line 99.

syslog-ng documentation: http://www.balabit.com/support/documentation/?product=syslog-ng
mailing list: https://lists.balabit.hu/mailman/listinfo/syslog-ng
 failed!
```

This is the part of syslog-ng.conf

```
9. filter f_auth { facility(auth, authpriv) and not filter(f_debug); };
94. filter f_cron { facility(cron) and not filter(f_debug); };
95. filter f_daemon { facility(daemon) and not filter(f_debug); };
96. filter f_kern { facility(kern) and not filter(f_debug); };
97. filter f_lpr { facility(lpr) and not filter(f_debug); };
98. filter f_local { facility(local0, local1, local3, local4, local5,
99.                         local6, local7) and not filter(f_debug); };
100. filter f_mail { facility(mail) and not filter(f_debug); };
101. filter f_news { facility(news) and not filter(f_debug); };
102. filter f_syslog3 { not facility(auth, authpriv, mail) and not filter(f_debug); };
103. filter f_user { facility(user) and not filter(f_debug); };
104. filter f_uucp { facility(uucp) and not filter(f_debug); };
```

Do you have any idea, what could be wrong?
Operating system is Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put line 98 and 99 in one line:

> filter f_local { facility(local0, local1, local3, local4, local5, local6, local7) and not filter(f_debug); };

if you need two lines use the `\` at the end of the first line:

> filter f_local { facility(local0, local1, local3, local4, local5, \
>
> local6, local7) and not filter(f_debug); };

Comment: That is what i thought first but it fails to start again just not saying why: # /etc/init.d/syslog-ng reload
Reload system logging: syslog-ng failed!

Comment: Line wrap is ignored - you don't need a \, please paste your entire config.

Comment: The problem was completely on another side. It's ok. Thank you.